# How do I fix being able to view photos sent to me in Messages on my Mac?

Tags: macos, photos, messages, preview, monterey

I have an issue (which may have started when I updated macOS to Monterey) where I cannot view images in Messages threads like how I used to see view them. IIRC I used to be able to either double click and/or tap  when a message was selected, and I'd be shown a larger version. However now the only way I can seem to view a larger version is to double click on the thumbnail, and then double click again.

Here is the thumbnail in the thread: [image]

If I double click it, I get here: [image]

Then I can double click again to open in Photos or Preview (not sure how it decides which of these 2 apps to use).

I'd love to be able to view the photo enlarged, without being taken to another app.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug. I am on M1 iMac and sometimes this starts happening.

- To fix it, QUIT Messages app and launch it again!

When you do this things magically open in preview again.

This is how things used to work in the past by default. I don't understand why you would want use the Photos app for this, most of the pictures I receive via iMessage are something I do not want to save into my photos or really anywhere. And that extra dialog doesn't even offer Preview to open up the image only Photos + share options.

Hope that helps!